# How can I show % values on the y axis of a plot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, mathematica-8

In any Mathematica chart or plot how can I show % values on the y axis?

I may have data like this:

```
data = {{{2010, 8, 3}, 0.}, {{2010, 8, 31}, -0.052208}, {{2010, 9, 30}, 
  0.008221}, {{2010, 10, 29}, 0.133203}, {{2010, 11, 30}, 
  0.044557}, {{2010, 12, 31}, 0.164891}, {{2011, 1, 31}, 
  0.055141}, {{2011, 2, 28}, 0.114801}, {{2011, 3, 31}, 
  0.170501}, {{2011, 4, 29}, 0.347566}, {{2011, 5, 31}, 
  0.461358}, {{2011, 6, 30}, 0.244649}, {{2011, 7, 29}, 
  0.41939}, {{2011, 8, 31}, 0.589874}, {{2011, 9, 30}, 
  0.444151}, {{2011, 10, 31}, 0.549095}, {{2011, 11, 30}, 0.539669}};

DateListPlot@data
```

I just want the y axis to range from 0% to 60% instead of 0.0 to 0.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `FrameTicks -> {{left, right},{bottom, up}}`

```
DateListPlot[data, 
             FrameTicks -> {{{{0.0, "0%"}, {0.1, "10%"}, {0.2, "20%"}, 
                              {0.3, "30%"}, {0.4, "40%"}, {0.5, "50%"}, 
                              {0.6, "60%"}}, None}, 
                            {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

The table for `FrameTicks` can be generated, e.g.,

```
Table[{k/10., ToString@(10 k) <> "%"}, {k, 6}]
(* Out[10] := {{0.1, "10%"}, {0.2, "20%"}, {0.3, "30%"}, {0.4, "40%"}, {0.5, "50%"}, {0.6, "60%"}} *)
```

If you need to make a lot of figures there is [LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/), a free package that makes producing good plots in Mathematica much easier, especially when it comes to tick marks.

EDIT: As per Jagra's suggestion here is a function that makes a tick specification list based on the data set and with desired tick steps. Assumptions are that the data structure is the always the same.

```
ticks[step_, data_] := {{Table[{k, ToString@IntegerPart@(100 k) <> "%"}, 
                               {k, 
                                Floor[Min@data[[All, 2]], step],
                                Ceiling[Max@data[[All, 2]], step], 
                                step}], None}, 
                         {Automatic, None}};
```

Now you can define a plotting function

```
plot = DateListPlot[#, FrameTicks -> ticks[.1, #]] &
```

and use it like this `plot@data`

Finally, since your question specifies *any* Mathematica plot, remember that `FrameTicks` works only on framed plots, for other plots use `Ticks -> {{x ticks},{y ticks}}`.

Comment: I tried the following to more automate the solution, given I won't know the plots range before hand.  One could probably simplify it further:  DateListPlot[data, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{k/10., ToString@(10 k) <> "%"}, {k, 
      IntegerPart[Floor[Min@data[[All, 2]], .1]*10], 
      IntegerPart[Ceiling[Max@data[[All, 2]], .1]*10]
      }], None}, {Automatic, None}}]

Answer (score 6):

You could try fiddling with `FrameTicks`:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your y-axis values are given as ratios and you want them as percentages, the simplest solution is:

```
DateListPlot[{#1, 100 #2} & @@@ data]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I do not see the graphics options, such a possibility, but you can create an intermediate function that will convert your number to the right. You're going to display the graph of this function. This can be done easily.
Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry to say but this answer, apart from being vague and almost devoid of information, is also dead wrong.