# Mathematica, FrameTicks inconsistency across different kinds of plots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, mathematica-8

I came across some unexpected inconsistencies when further developing the solution to an earlier question:

[How can I show % values on the y axis of a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359329/how-can-i-show-values-on-the-y-axis-of-a-plot)

This seemed different enough to merit a new post.

Starting with the same data:

```
data = {{{2010, 8, 3}, 
0.}, {{2010, 8, 31}, -0.052208}, {{2010, 9, 30}, 
0.008221}, {{2010, 10, 29}, 0.133203}, {{2010, 11, 30}, 
0.044557}, {{2010, 12, 31}, 0.164891}, {{2011, 1, 31}, 
0.055141}, {{2011, 2, 28}, 0.114801}, {{2011, 3, 31}, 
0.170501}, {{2011, 4, 29}, 0.347566}, {{2011, 5, 31}, 
0.461358}, {{2011, 6, 30}, 0.244649}, {{2011, 7, 29}, 
0.41939}, {{2011, 8, 31}, 0.589874}, {{2011, 9, 30}, 
0.444151}, {{2011, 10, 31}, 0.549095}, {{2011, 11, 30}, 
0.539669}};
```

I defined a way to make `FrameTicks` with percentages built on the contributions and insights offered in the last post:

```
myFrameTicks = 
Table[
  {k/10., ToString@(10 k) <> "%"}, 
  {
    k, 
    IntegerPart[Floor[Min@data[[All, 2]], .1]*10], 
    IntegerPart[Ceiling[Max@data[[All, 2]], .1]*10]
   }
 ];
```

Now look at two plots of the same data using the same `FrameTicks`:

```
DateListPlot[data, FrameTicks -> {{myFrameTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[data[[All, 2]], FrameTicks -> {{myFrameTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, why don't both of these plots show the frame ticks as percentage (e.g., 60%) like the first one does?

I might have missed something obvious (not the first time).  Also, this approach doesn't appear to work when used with `ListLinePlot` or `BarChart`, both of which seem to accept a `FrameTicks` attribute.

Comment: I did mention this in my (accepted, thank you) answer toyour question :-). Maybe I should have stressed it more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateListPlot` defaults to `Frame->True`. `ListPlot` defaults to `Frame->False`. It is displaying Ticks, not FrameTicks.

Try setting the `Frame` to true:

```
DateListPlot[data, 
  FrameTicks -> {{myFrameTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]

ListPlot[data[[All, 2]], 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{myFrameTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

Comment: David, I have not seen much from you recently.  It's good to have you back!

Comment: Thanks, I've been checking in from time to time but hadn't found many places I could contribute.

Comment: @DavidCarraher -- For my part, very nice to have you around.

Comment: @Jagra Thanks. That's nice to hear.

Answer (score 2):

We have `FrameTicks` for `Frame`, and `Ticks` for `Axes`, so in addition to David's solution of turning on the frame for `ListPlot`, you could instead specify your function for `Ticks`:

```
ListPlot[data[[All, 2]], Ticks -> {Automatic, myFrameTicks}]
```

(Note the difference in ordering.)